# HTTPS and CORS with Sony Camera API

Tags: camera, sony, sony-camera-api

I am developing a web application which makes use of the Sony Camera API with an Alpha 6300.

The web-app needs to access the camera and internet at the same time. Therefore, I am using a laptop with two network adapters, one connecting to Wi-Fi and one to the camera access point. I got this to work without the discovery phase, which is not possible from a browser (that's ok, the IP address of the camera is always the same).

However, in order to get it working on the production server (which is secure), I need some ugly hacks, due to the camera endpoints being only available in HTTP (no HTTPS) and with no CORS headers:

- I need to use a Chrome extension to bypass CORS
- I need to click on 'load unsafe scripts' in Google Chrome

A quick solution would be to pack everything in an Electron app, thus overriding Chrome's (more than legitimate) security concerns. However, this would strongly complicate the deploying and testing process. I would rather go with a web-based solution, if possible.

Anybody knows if there's a way to enforce HTTPS and set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` on the Camera server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a local CORS proxy. That's what I've done for development.

I went the similar route of "Electron" for disabling the same origin policy, only I used PhoneGap because I needed this for a phone.

Comment: Yes, that's an option for development... However, that wouldn't work in a live deployment. Very disappointed by Sony support, hoped somebody could shed some light on how to do this properly.

Comment: Well yes. It would be nice if it just had enabled the CORS headers on the camera. I hate to have to create an 'app' only to do this. Especially as development is more clunky than for web. But with CORS proxy, at least some things can be quickly done on the PC.